# How to press 'enter to continue' in automated install with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano

I'm using capistrano to install nginx among other services as described by Ryan Bates in this Railscasts. The nginx.rb file below is copied from his source code. When the installation process gets to the line

```
* executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable"
```

it throws a warning and asks me to confirm by pressing ENTER or control c to continue. However, since this is not a manual installation, I can't press enter  to continue. The installation script is frozen waiting for a command that I can't enter manually. Is there a way to modify the nginx.rb file below to deal with this type of situation?

```
        triggering after callbacks for `deploy:install'
  * 2013-07-11 10:17:36 executing `nginx:install'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable"
    servers: ["192.XXX.XXX.XXX"]
    [192.XXX.XXX.XXX] executing command
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] Stable version of nginx.
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] The following are no longer updated past 1.2.7, due to PPA build restrictions:
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] * Maverick
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] The following will not be updated past 1.4.1, except for bugfixes which may have been missed:
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] * Lucid
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] * Natty
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] * Oneiric
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] More info: https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/stable
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX] Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
 ** [out :: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX]
```

nginx.rb

```
namespace :nginx do
  desc "Install latest stable release of nginx"
  task :install, roles: :web do
    run "#{sudo} add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable"
    run "#{sudo} apt-get -y update"
    run "#{sudo} apt-get -y install nginx"
  end
  after "deploy:install", "nginx:install"

  desc "Setup nginx configuration for this application"
  task :setup, roles: :web do
    template "nginx_unicorn.erb", "/tmp/nginx_conf"
    run "#{sudo} mv /tmp/nginx_conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    run "#{sudo} rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default"
    restart
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "nginx:setup"

  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} nginx"
    task command, roles: :web do
      run "#{sudo} service nginx #{command}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is solution in comments right for that railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/337-capistrano-recipes?view=comments, see Breno Santos Salgado question.

One of solutions provided by him is

```
task :install, roles: :web do
  run "#{sudo} add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable",:pty => true do |ch, stream, data|
    if data =~ /Press.\[ENTER\].to.continue/
      #prompt, and then send the response to the remote process
      ch.send_data(Capistrano::CLI.password_prompt("Press enter to continue:") + "\n")
    else
      #use the default handler for all other text
      Capistrano::Configuration.default_io_proc.call(ch,stream,data)
    end
  end

  run "#{sudo} apt-get -y update"
  run "#{sudo} apt-get -y install nginx"
end
```

You can find some refactored ways to do it there too, choose what suits you the best.

Comment: @Mohamad I've got no experience with capistrano 3, sorry.

Comment: @biomancer Figured it out a while ago. It actually works for Capistrano 2 and 3. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way using `echo`.

**Capistrano 2**

```
run "echo | #{sudo} add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable"
```

**Capistrano 3**

```
execute 'echo | add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable'
```